# Создание боковой панели админки вордпресс

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, фреймворк, админка

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно по больше ознакомится с добавлением функционала в админку вордпресс? Чтоб можно было добавлять превью картинки и не только. Просто когда смотрю разные уроки на ютюбе, там у разработчиков и календари, и загрузчики картинок, и добавление/редактирование форм, вообщем куча всего стоит. Где подобные блоки стоят либо с правой стороны, либо над/под текстовым редактором. Но как это они сделали, в комментариях никто не отвечает. Т.к. встречал авторские блоки, и частенько от фрэйворков. Может есть уроки, где про это можно по подробнее узнать? Может сайты полезные есть по этому поводу? Подскажите кому не трудно.

Про фрэймворки и плагины я знаю, но как это все устроено и как это все делается, вот что мне бы очень хотелось узнать.

Поймите меня правильно, я не прошу у вас написать для меня код, мне бы очень хочется это самому сделать. С ворпрессом я только неделю знаком, до этого была только джумла. А с php я в хороших отношениях, поэтому написать конкретный код я смогу. Вопрос лишь в том, как этот код заставить работать в самом вордпресс-е.

[image: боковая панель админки вордпресс]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна стандартная функция [add_meta_box](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_meta_box).

> как это все устроено и как это все делается, вот что мне бы очень
>   хотелось узнать.

Применительно к WordPress есть хорошая [официальная документация](https://codex.wordpress.org/). Плюс статьи на профильных блогах (легко ищутся через гугл).

Comment: О да! Спасибо большое. То что надо!